# Chrome reports request with 304 status code response as cancelled

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome-devtools

When returning a 304 `Not modified` status code from an MVC controller:

```
public IActionResult NotModified()
{
    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
}
```

Chrome will mark the request as cancelled, the same happens when manipulating the response directly. I'm assuming this is behaviour of Chrome. As the text is displayed in red, this seems to be an error. Other browsers just show the 304 response.

[image]

Is this problematic and do I need to make any changes to have it displayed as a correct request?

When using https://httpstat.us/304 you can check this as well, it's not asp.net related.